# Theme.of(context).colorScheme does not have the expected colors

Tags: flutter

I decided to write a small app to display all the colors available in the `ColorScheme` of the `MaterialApp` theme.

According to the `ColorScheme.fromSeed` documentation this constructor generates a `ColorScheme` derived from the given `seedColor`. The 30 colors of the `ColorScheme` can be accessed by using `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.xxxx`, where xxxx is the desired color (e.g. primary, secondary, tertiary, etc.). Well, it is not happening. The app below creates a `ColorScheme` from a green seed and displays 30 tiles with the supposed respective colors. The colors are coming out all wrong, mostly blues. However, the `appBar` shows the correct green color. So what am I doing wrong? I have searched high and low for an answer to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant documentation:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/ColorScheme.fromSeed.html

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ColorScheme cs = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.green),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Center(child: Text('Colors'))),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView(children: [
            MyColorTile(cs.primary, 'primary'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onPrimary, 'onPrimary'),
            MyColorTile(cs.primaryContainer, 'primaryContainer'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onPrimaryContainer, 'onPrimaryContainer'),
            MyColorTile(cs.secondary, 'secondary'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onSecondary, 'onSecondary'),
            MyColorTile(cs.secondaryContainer, 'secondaryContainer'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onSecondaryContainer, 'onSecondaryContainer'),
            MyColorTile(cs.tertiary, 'tertiary'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onTertiary, 'onTertiary'),
            MyColorTile(cs.tertiaryContainer, 'tertiaryContainer'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onTertiaryContainer, 'onTertiaryContainer'),
            MyColorTile(cs.error, 'error'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onError, 'onError'),
            MyColorTile(cs.errorContainer, 'errorContainer'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onErrorContainer, 'onErrorContainer'),
            MyColorTile(cs.outline, 'outline'),
            MyColorTile(cs.outlineVariant, 'outlineVariant'),
            MyColorTile(cs.background, 'background'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onBackground, 'onBackground'),
            MyColorTile(cs.surface, 'surface'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onSurface, 'onSurface'),
            MyColorTile(cs.surfaceVariant, 'surfaceVariant'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onSurfaceVariant, 'onSurfaceVariant'),
            MyColorTile(cs.inverseSurface, 'inverseSurface'),
            MyColorTile(cs.onInverseSurface, 'onInverseSurface'),
            MyColorTile(cs.inversePrimary, 'inversePrimary'),
            MyColorTile(cs.shadow, 'shadow'),
            MyColorTile(cs.scrim, 'scrim'),
            MyColorTile(cs.surfaceTint, 'surfaceTint'),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyColorTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final String label;
  const MyColorTile(this.color, this.label, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: color,
        title: Text(label, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the ColorScheme cs variable from a context that hasn't gotten the colorScheme defined yet.  Try this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.green),
      ),
      home: MainView(),
    );
  }
}

class MainView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ColorScheme cs = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Center(child: Text('Colors'))),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(children: [
          MyColorTile(cs.primary, 'primary'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onPrimary, 'onPrimary'),
          MyColorTile(cs.primaryContainer, 'primaryContainer'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onPrimaryContainer, 'onPrimaryContainer'),
          MyColorTile(cs.secondary, 'secondary'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onSecondary, 'onSecondary'),
          MyColorTile(cs.secondaryContainer, 'secondaryContainer'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onSecondaryContainer, 'onSecondaryContainer'),
          MyColorTile(cs.tertiary, 'tertiary'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onTertiary, 'onTertiary'),
          MyColorTile(cs.tertiaryContainer, 'tertiaryContainer'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onTertiaryContainer, 'onTertiaryContainer'),
          MyColorTile(cs.error, 'error'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onError, 'onError'),
          MyColorTile(cs.errorContainer, 'errorContainer'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onErrorContainer, 'onErrorContainer'),
          MyColorTile(cs.outline, 'outline'),
          MyColorTile(cs.outlineVariant, 'outlineVariant'),
          MyColorTile(cs.background, 'background'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onBackground, 'onBackground'),
          MyColorTile(cs.surface, 'surface'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onSurface, 'onSurface'),
          MyColorTile(cs.surfaceVariant, 'surfaceVariant'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onSurfaceVariant, 'onSurfaceVariant'),
          MyColorTile(cs.inverseSurface, 'inverseSurface'),
          MyColorTile(cs.onInverseSurface, 'onInverseSurface'),
          MyColorTile(cs.inversePrimary, 'inversePrimary'),
          MyColorTile(cs.shadow, 'shadow'),
          MyColorTile(cs.scrim, 'scrim'),
          MyColorTile(cs.surfaceTint, 'surfaceTint'),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyColorTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final String label;
  const MyColorTile(this.color, this.label, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: color,
        title: Text(label, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @John Weidner. I have yet to master the subtleties and nuance of Flutter/Dart.

Comment: It's easy to forget that BuildContext is NOT a global that is the same everywhere. You can find several tutorials that try to explain BuildContext.